# Installing and configuring open source tools that are unmanaged, with command line access, in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but I am looking to create an architecture in Amazon AWS, but do not want to use all managed services. For example, I want to install an unmanaged version of Apache Kafka. Can I install and configure open source tools like this with command line access, and have full control over the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create an EC2 instance and do whatever you like on it, just like any other Linux server.

Beware that AWS is a complex enterprise platform, not a simple hosting service. You really need to be aware of security issues if you're going to put resources on AWS.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.